# How to manage a collection of views that have independant outlets?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

- Code is here: https://github.com/midu/form_builder/
- Live version: http://midu.github.com/form_builder/#/forms

Is there a way, when you are rendering several times a view, to have each of them associated with an instance of a controller?

Pretty sure it's not the right way of doing it, so I'm open to indications on how I should be doing it. But here is the use case:

I have these routes:

```js
FormBuilder.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  // ...
  form: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/form/:form_id/edit',
    connectOutlets: function (router, form) {
      router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('editForm', form);
      router.get('editFormController').connectOutlet( 'fieldsList', form.get('fields') );
    },

    editField: Ember.Route.transitionTo('editOneField'),
    showField: Ember.Route.transitionTo('showOneField'),

    initialState: 'showOneField',
    editOneField: Ember.Route.extend({
      connectOutlets: function (router, field) {
        router.get('fieldsListController').connectOutlet('editField', field);
      }
    }),
    showOneField: Ember.Route.extend({
      connectOutlets: function (router, field) {
        router.get('fieldsListController').connectOutlet('showField', field);
      }
    })
  })
});
```

I am trying to list the `Field`s in a `Form` in the `form` route. The `Route` for this is:

```
  form: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/form/:form_id/edit',
    connectOutlets: function (router, form) {
      router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('editForm', form);
      router.get('editFormController').connectOutlet( 'fieldsList', form.get('fields') );
    },
```

`EditFormView` renders the template `edit_form_view`:

```html
<h2>Editing form {{id}}</h2>

{{view FormBuilder.AddFormFieldsView}}

{{ outlet }}
```

In which we connect the `outlet` to the `fieldsList`. This renders the `fields_list` template, and is connected to the `FieldsListController` controller, which is an array `Field`.

```html
{{! fields_list.handlebards }}
<p>The form fields</p>

<ul>
{{#each content}}
  {{view FormBuilder.FieldView}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

So this renders the view `FieldView` which uses the `field_view` template:

```html
# {{publicName}}

{{outlet}}
```

And this is where I have a problem. I can't really "connect" this `outlet`, because it's part of the `fieldsListController`.

I will describe what I try to do. I have this in my controller.

```js
editField: Ember.Route.transitionTo('editOneField'),
showField: Ember.Route.transitionTo('showOneField'),

initialState: 'showOneField',
editOneField: Ember.Route.extend({
  connectOutlets: function (router, field) {
    router.get('fieldsListController').connectOutlet('editField', field);
  }
}),
showOneField: Ember.Route.extend({
  connectOutlets: function (router, field) {
    router.get('fieldsListController').connectOutlet('showField', field);
  }
})
```

Which means that when rendering the view, the `outlet` in `field_view.handlebars` will be connected with `showField`:

```html
<pre>show a field yo :)</pre>

<a {{action editField this}}>(edit)</a>
```

If I only have one field, and click on `(edit)`, it will switch connect the `outlet` with `editField`, which is so far what I am trying to do. However, if there is more than 1 `Field` in my `Form`, when I press `(edit)`, it connects ALL the `outlet`s to `editField`.

It makes sense because of this `router.get('fieldsListController').connectOutlet('showField', field);`, but I don't know how to get the right instance of a controller (and/or create an instance of a controller for each of the `FieldView`s.

I am quite lost right here. I am trying to do "inline edition" without changing the entire view and it doesn't seem to be good documentation/tutorials about having a collection of views that each has an independent `outlet`...

The links to the entire code base and an online live version is on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `{{control}}` helper which is under development, but accessible in Ember.js [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/control.js#L20). This helper is designed so that it **instantiates a controller** for each use of this helper.